# House plant with no name

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care, container-gardening, palm

Just received thus beautiful plant. Can anyone help with identification and care?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a young [Rhapis Palm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhapis_excelsa). It an excellent long lived palm as it tolerates the lower light levels of interior locations. To keep the plant at it's best provide bright filtered light and do not overwater. This plant is unlikely to flower or set seed until it's mature which should take many years.

Keys for identification are:

- fibrous brown sheaths around the base of the stems
- varied leaf shapes. In young specimens you will see leaves that are single and thin, some have wide fronds.
- veins in the leaves are parallel to the main rib. Many other plants have veins which run forty five degrees from the main rib.